# How to Turn Off (Disable) Web Proxy Auto Discovery (WPAD) in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows

We have a web service that is running slowly in production.  In QA and UAT it is fine but those are housed at our corporate HQs.  But production is in a data center in the cloud.  I ran wireshark and found that it is making at least 6 calls to NBNS WPAD (each one timing out), each taking about 3/4 of a second making it very slow.  I want to turn off WPAD since the environment is not configured to use it but it is still making the calls and just wasting time.

My platform is windows server 2008 r2 with IE9.  I want to completely disable WPAD DNS queries (and NBNS queries).  We don't use a proxy.  We don't use DHCP.  I want to stop WPAD but I haven't been successful.  I have tried the following:
1.disable "automatically detect settings" in IE
2.disable "use automatic configuration script" in IE
3.Checked that  WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service is not running automatically, it is set to run manual so I think that should be ok.
4.Executed "Netsh winhttp show proxy" which tells me Direct access (no proxy server).

What am I missing that needs to be turned off?

Answer (score 8):

Many suggestions around disabling WPAD focus on Internet Explorer user settings.  While this will tell IE to not use auto proxy detection, it will not stop the WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service from querying for wpad.  Some have suggested disabling this service entirely, but as of Windows 10, it is required for the IP Helper service and not recommended to disable it.

In the [MS16-063](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS16-063) notes, you can see their suggested workaround for the (fixed) vulnerability is to edit the hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).

```
255.255.255.255 wpad.
```

Although the patch fixed that specific vulnerability, the workaround is still an option for disabling WPAD.  In my testing, it does stop the queries.  As the article notes:

> **Impact of workaround**. Autoproxy discovery will not work, and for this reason, some applications, such as Internet Explorer, will not be able to load websites properly.

Keep in mind that WPAD can be a good thing when setup properly.  As with any advice from the Internet, be sure to do your own testing before applying any changes. For example, if you make this change to corporate laptops and they travel to a site that requires WPAD, they will not work.

Source: [Microsoft forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a97604d6-b6d1-41e5-b6fc-dbbccebf570d/disable-wpad-dns-querys-completly?forum=winservergen).

*Note that you can easily use Wireshark to see if a computer is doing wpad queries by using the filter:*   **`dns.qry.name contains "wpad"`**

Comment: In Windows 10, one can go to Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy and disable 'Automatically detect settings'. Or one can also search for 'Internet Properties'  and go to LAN Settings, and turn off 'Automatically detect settings'. Though the 'Internet Properties' UI is also triggered from IE, I don't think it only applies to IE. For example, Chrome will respect the OS setting. With auto detect settings on, chrome://net-internals/#proxy will report the original and effective settings, and if it's off, chrome://net-internals/#proxy only reports the effective setting.

Comment: I know the op asked about Windows Server, but since you mentioned Windows 10 I thought to comment about the case for end users.

Comment: With respect to your link on MS16-063, apparently Microsoft has issued a fix in an update https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms16-077

Comment: Right, thanks for sharing. Once you apply the share dny.qry.name contains "wpad", can you trace it back to a software or where it comes from? KR

Answer (score 2):

Group Policy Editor
Edit "Default Domain Policy"
User Configuration
 Policies
  Windows Settings
    Connection/Automatic Browser Configuration
      Automatically detect configuration settings -> DISABLE

Answer (score 1):

I have tested removing proxy from computers by renaming the WPAD key and rebooting.
You can also use IEAK11 to create a GPO to remove "Automatically detect settings" and that is why the script uses gpupdate to apply the GPO as well. 
If you already applied the change to a computer this script won't do changes and will exit. The basic script is bellow.

Even when you turn on in Internet Explorer "Automatically detect settings" proxy is not used and WPAD key is recreated but with no proxy. This setting is no longer recommended as makes your computer vulnerable (https://it.slashdot.org/story/16/08/13/0149241/disable-wpad-now-or-have-your-accounts-compromised-researchers-warn) .

```
REM Script to delete the cached proxy configuration, clear IE cache, flushdns, rename WPAD key and delete the original; reboot is required

gpupdate 

reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad.bad" >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 goto END

ELSE 
(
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections" /v "DefaultConnectionSettings" /f
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections" /v "SavedLegacySettings" /f

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

ipconfig /flushdns

reg copy "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad.bad"

reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad" /f

echo n | gpupdate /force /wait:0

shutdown.exe /r /t 30 )

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

for my pihole (Raspberry PI based ad blocking software DNS level) i added the below in the hosts file

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost

0.0.0.0 wpad wpad.my.home
:: wpad wpad.my.home
```

and my  nslookup shows

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup wpad.my.home
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   wpad.my.home
Address: 0.0.0.0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup wpad
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   wpad
Address: 0.0.0.0
```

if you are on a Windows machine you can open "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" and add these entries

```
0.0.0.0 wpad
0.0.0.0 wpad.my.home
```

change my.home to whatever local domain you have

Comment: Does `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.255` (as other sources says) result in the same behaviour?